# Trouble using stored procedure to insert query results into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do some testing on some tables but I seem to keep running into an error.

I'm trying to run the following stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO [Customer].[TableA_test] ([CustomerID], [VisitID], [TransactionId], [ArrivalDT], [DataA], [DataB], [DataC], [SnapDate]) 
    SELECT
        b.CustomerID,   
        b.VisitID,
        b.TransactionID,
        b.ArrivalDT,
        b.DataA,
        b.DataB,
        b.DataC,
        SnapDate = GETDATE()
    FROM 
        [Customer].[TableA_test] a
    LEFT JOIN 
        [Customer].[TableB] b ON a.VisitID = b.VisitID
                              AND a.TransactionId = b.TransactionID
    WHERE 
        a.TransactionID IS NULL
```

The procedure is meant to take the results from the query and insert them into the TableA. Table A has the exact same columns and data types as TableB. When I try to execute the stored procedure (code provided above), I get the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertTo_TableA_test, Line 27
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

All of my date columns are set to `datetime` data type: `ArrivalDT` and the `SnapDate`. TableA_testing and TableB have the exact same column names and datatypes.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here's the table info for [Customer].[TableA_test]:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer].[TableA_test]
(
    [TransactionID] [VARCHAR](254) NULL,
    [VisitID] [VARCHAR](254) NULL,
    [ArrivalDT] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [CustomerID] [VARCHAR](254) NULL,
    [DataA] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [DataB] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [DataC] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [SnapDate] [DATETIME] NULL
)
```

And for TableB:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer].[TableB]
(
    [TransactionID] [VARCHAR](254) NULL,
    [VisitID] [VARCHAR](254) NULL,
    [ArrivalDT] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [CustomerID] [VARCHAR](254) NULL,
    [DataA] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [DataB] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [DataC] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [SnapDate] [DATETIME] NULL
)
```

Line 27 of my stored procedure is:

```
INSERT INTO [Customer].[JTM_NY_SPARCS_VitalSigns_test] ([CustomerID],[VisitID], [TransactionID], [ArrivalDT], [DataA], [DataB], [DataC], [SnapDate])
```

[image: Data result example]

Here's the full read-out of the stored procedure:

```
USE [Database_3]

GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Customer].[InsertTo_TableA_test]    Script Date: 4/12/2019 11:49:17 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




CREATE PROCEDURE [Customer].[InsertTo_TableA_test]


/*
CREATED: 04/11/2019
*/


AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [Customer].[TableA_test] ([CustomerID], [VisitID], [TransactionId], [ArrivalDT], [DataA], [DataB], [DataC], [SnapDate]) 
        SELECT
            b.CustomerID,   
            b.VisitID,
            b.TransactionID,
            b.ArrivalDT,
            b.DataA,
            b.DataB,
            b.DataC,
            SnapDate = GETDATE()
        FROM 
            [Customer].[TableA_test] a
        LEFT JOIN 
            [Customer].[TableB] b ON a.VisitID = b.VisitID
                                  AND a.TransactionId = b.TransactionID
        WHERE 
            a.TransactionID IS NULL

END





GO
```

Example of a row of results when running the query from the stored procedure:

```
100010 [VisitID]      
20000281542 [TransactionID]    
2014-07-09 15:44:42.000 [ArrivalDT] 
0032011 [CustomerID]     
147 [DataA]    
71 [DataB]  
69 [DataC]  
2019-04-12 11:54:23.753 [SnapDate]
```

Comment: Is that statement doing what you intend anyway? It's inserting data, from table `[TableB]` into table `TableA_test`  if it there are no rows joined to in  the table `TableB` (match from `TableA_test`). That would just insert a bunch of `NULL` values (apart from `SnapDate` which would have the current value of `GETDATE()` inserted).

Comment: @Larnu He's inserting data from `[Customer].[TableB]` into `TableA_Test`, look at the aliases in the `Select`

Comment: Not exactly. My code may be faulty. I'm trying to move a bunch of data I have in TableA_test over to TableB. I'm joining TableB in order to exclude any duplicate rows.

Comment: He is @RyanWilson yes, but his `FROM` is `[Customer].[TableA_test]` with a `LEFT JOIN` on `[TableB]`, specifically on `a.TransactionId = b.TransactionID` (that's important). The OP's `WHERE` is `b.TransactionID IS NULL` and as `NULL` can never equal `NULL` then no rows will ever be returned from `TableB`.

Comment: Your query looks okay.  Perhaps you have a trigger that is causing the problem.

Comment: Might be useful if you gave some sample data and signify which line is line 27 in your proc.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's actually not. If `b.TransactionID IS NULL` is true, then `a.TransactionId = b.TransactionID` cannot be true, by definition of how `NULL` works. This would mean that regardless of the result set, every value in the `SELECT` will have the value `NULL` apart from `GETDATE()`

Comment: @Larnu you're absolutely right. That was a type when I was creating the post. It's supposed to be "a.TransactionID IS NULL". That was just a typo on here, though. I'm still getting the same error regardless.

Comment: Post the DDL in your question, not in the comments (and update your SQL in your post, if it is incorrect, new visitors may not read the comments)

Comment: @Larnu Good catch on the `NULL` comparison. :)

Comment: @RyanWilson I updated the post with more information, including the code from line 27.

Comment: @Larnu I added additional information to the post which may make it easier to analyze.

Comment: Try a datetime2...

Comment: That picture looks like it from Excel, not SQL Server. Can you provide sample data as  text, not an image please, which **replicates** the issue?

Comment: @Larnu. You're right. I did grab it from Excel to edit the data for customer security. I copied a row from SQL Server and pasted it to the post for you (text this time, not an image). Thanks.

Comment: might be a silly question. Why your data (the last line) is not in sequence as your select query above? CustomerID is selected first, but your data shows CustomerID as 4th column. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen in your comments, you said you are trying to insert from TableA_test to TableB. If that is the case, then your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO [Customer].[TableB] ([CustomerID],[VisitID],[TransactionId],[ArrivalDT],[DataA],[DataB],[DataC],[SnapDate]) 

SELECT
    a.CustomerID,   
    a.VisitID,
    a.TranactionID,
    a.ArrivalDT,
    a.DataA,
    a.DataB,
    a.DataC,
    SnapDate = GETDATE()

FROM [Customer].[TableA_test] a
LEFT JOIN [Customer].[TableB] b
    ON a.VisitID = b.VisitID
        AND a.TransactionId = b.TransactionID
WHERE b.TransactionID IS NULL
```

Comment: `SnapDate` would be an alias in the context. try `SELECT SnapDate = GETDATE();` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Larnu. In that context, my answer won't be applicable.

Comment: I still don't see any obvious issues with the query. Do you @Larnu?

Comment: I think we're missing key information, like DDL, Sabhari.

Comment: @Larnu: I added the script out of the full stored procedure to the post. :)